# Backbone Marionette get region view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a marionette layout that has a region with a view inside. How can I get a reference to that view?

For example:

```
var layoutView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    regions: {
        myRegion: '.some-element'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        this.myView.show(new someView());
    },
    test: function(){
        var view = this.myRegion.get() // or something to retrieve the view?
    }
});
```

I mean, I can save the view instance into "this", but surely marionette must have a way of retrieving it...right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It should just be `this.myRegion.currentView`
and model if bound to view:  `myRegion.currentView.model`

Comment: i know for sure this works on regions bound to the main app. R u sure test runs after show?

Comment: you also have an error in initialize. it should be myRegion.show(...)